# Redirect Loop - IIS7

Tags: redirect, iis-7, url-rewriting

Getting a redirect loop when using the below rule on IIS7 using the rewrite module.

```
         <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="test" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/new/test" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to redirect from http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com

Believe the correct pattern should be "^domain\.com$"

This matches the entire HTTP_HOST value of "domain.com"

Comment: makes sense, will give this a try now. Thanks

Comment: For some reason applying ^ on the match url value i.e <match url="^test" /> has actually fixed it. Thanks